# Best Performance testing tool for AX Retail POS R3

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

i am looking for a best performance testing tool that can be used for AX-Retail R3 POS application. also, currently application is very slow and it runs in 32 bit mode in x64 architecture.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try the official [tools for performance monitoring](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us//library/jj149695.aspx).

Your implication that 32 bit mode is the reason is unfounded.